# Is the focus power test used for Opposed Willpower techniques?

Tags: warhammer-40k, rogue-trader

***A psyker makes a focus power test to use a psychic technique, he succeeds with 2 degrees of success.***

However, the psychic technique requires an Opposed Willpower check.

In this situation, what should happen next?

- The Psyker and his target make Willpower checks and oppose them.
- The target makes a Willpower check and opposes it to the Focus Power test.

I feel like it should be option 2 because it would make your Psy-Rating relevant to the difficulty of the check but I didn't find any rules that explains how exactly this should go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an [official errata](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/rogue-trader/support/faq1-4/Rogue%20Trader%20Errata%20v.%201.4%20WQ.pdf) that clarifies the ruling. Under Focus Power (page 4), we read :

> If the Focus Power Test is an Opposed Test, the Psyker must
> successfully pass the Test and gain more successes than at least one of
> his opponents to activate the Technique.

So we use the Focus Power test indeed.